# Find a Relation array and object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, case

```js
let data = [{
    name: "Sarah",
    year: ["1924", "1936", "1948", "1960", "1972", "1984", "1996", "2008", "2020", "2032"]
  },
  {
    name: "Ann",
    year: ["1925", "1937", "1949", "1961", "1973", "1985", "1997", "2009", "2021", "2033"]
  }
];
```

we assign an array and inside the array has two objects and every object has got another array.

I want to ask user her birth year and select her name from object value from the name.

for example, if she was born in 1949 her name must be Ann or if she was born in 1960 her name must be Sarah.

I am thinking about two days but I couldn't solve this problem.

I don't want to write code if/else or case switches state. is there another code option?
I want to make a correlation between name and years.

I hope I explain well..

Comment: what happens if she was born in 1959? should her name be `undefined`?

Comment: we can do another years for other names.

Comment: You can return a default value with Nullish coalescing operator, kindly check @halilibrahimtosun

Comment: @halilibrahimtosun If any of these answers solve your problem, and you do not need any additional help, please consider accepting the answer. Thanks!

Comment: thanks guys these solutions helped me a lot.

Comment: @halilibrahimtosun happy to see that you are able to resolve, whichever answers made you help kindly accept and vote , so it will be helpful for future reference :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for

```js
let data = [{
  name: "Sarah",
  year: ["1924", "1936", "1948", "1960", "1972", "1984", "1996", "2008", "2020", "2032"]
}, {
  name: "Ann",
  year: ["1925", "1937", "1949", "1961", "1973", "1985", "1997", "2009", "2021", "2033"]
}];

function yearToName(year) {
  return data.find(x => x.year.includes(year)).name;
}

console.log(yearToName("1936"))
console.log(yearToName("1937"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this using [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes): find the entry whose years include what you're looking for, then pluck the name from it. Something like this:

```
function getName (searchYear) {
  const entry = data.find(({year}) => year.includes[searchYear]);
  return entry?.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not exactly what you wanted, but by setting up a lookup structure you can speed up and simplify the followin search steps. It will behave in a stable way, i. e. for years, where no name was defined an "undefined" will be returned.

```js
let data = [ 
     {name:"Sarah",
      year:["1924", "1936", "1948", "1960", "1972", "1984", "1996", "2008", "2020", "2032"]},
     {name:"Ann", 
      year:["1925", "1937", "1949", "1961", "1973", "1985", "1997", "2009", "2021", "2033"]}
    ];

// setup a looup structure:
data.lookup=data.reduce((a,{name,year})=>(year.forEach(y=>a[y]=name),a),{})

// run a test over many years:
for (let y=1923;y<2034;y++) data.lookup[y] && console.log(y,data.lookup[y]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function which will get the name

With these methods

1. [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) - to get the single object from the array of objects
2. [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) - to find the passed year present in the array of year
3. [?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) - Optional chaining , in order getting an error, it will return undefined or null
4. [??](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)  - Nullish coalescing operator, to return the right side when the left side is null or undefined

```js
let data = [{
  name: "Sarah",
  year: ["1924", "1936", "1948", "1960", "1972", "1984", "1996", "2008", "2020", "2032"]
}, {
  name: "Ann",
  year: ["1925", "1937", "1949", "1961", "1973", "1985", "1997", "2009", "2021", "2033"]
}];

const getTheName = (year) => data.find(datumn => datumn.year.includes(year))?.name ?? `Don't have a name`

console.log(getTheName('1924')) // Sarah
console.log(getTheName('1949')) // Ann
console.log(getTheName('2020')) //Don't have a name
```